# Request replacing colum name by @variable

Tags: c#, sql, wpf

I'm trying to develop an application on C# WPF and I try to set the name of the column in the request as @variable. I explain, i have a comboBox with some options. These options are my column's names. When I select one of these options, I have to write in a textBox a word. And when I click on the validation button, the function which executes the display of the table needs two parameters : the value of the combo box and the textbox. And would like to know if I can make a request like

```
SELECT * FROM customer WHERE @boxContent = @text
```

I think this is where the problem is.

Here is my code for for xml.cs :

```
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        //InitializeComponent();
        text = testBox.Text;
        afficheListe.ListeModif(text,boxContent);
    }

    private void ComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (ID.IsSelected)
        {
            boxContent = "id_client";
        }
        else if (Nom.IsSelected)
        {
            boxContent = "nom";
        }
        else if (Prenom.IsSelected)
        {
            boxContent = "prenom";
        }
        else if (Sexe.IsSelected)
        {
            boxContent = "sexe";
        }
        else if (DateNaissance.IsSelected)
        {
            boxContent = "date_Naiss";
        }
        else if (Mail.IsSelected)
        {
            boxContent = "mail";
        }
        else if (Adresse.IsSelected)
        {
            boxContent = "adresse";
        }
        else if (Pays.IsSelected)
        {
            boxContent = "pays";
        }
}
```

Here is my code for request' function :

```
public void ListeModif(string text, string boxContent)
{
        bdd.connection.Open();

        MySqlCommand cmd = bdd.connection.CreateCommand();
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@text", text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@boxContent", boxContent);

        cmd.CommandText = " SELECT * FROM client WHERE @boxContent = @text";

        MessageBox.Show(cmd.ToString());

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        clients.Clear();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            clients.Add(new Client()
            {
                Id = Convert.ToInt32(reader["id_Client"]),
                Nom = Convert.ToString(reader["nom"]),
                Prenom = Convert.ToString(reader["prenom"]),
                Sexe = Convert.ToString(reader["sexe"]),
                Date_Naissance = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["date_Naiss"]),
                Mail = Convert.ToString(reader["mail"]),
                Adresse = Convert.ToString(reader["adresse"]),
                Pays = Convert.ToString(reader["pays"])
            });
        }

        reader.Close();

        bdd.connection.Close();
}
```

When I use the debugger, the value of `cmd` variable is:

```
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand}
```

Hoping I explained my problem well.

Answer (score 1):

> And would like to know if i can make a request like
>
> "SELECT * FROM customer where @boxContent = @text "

No, you cannot.  In SQL (in general, not just in SQL Server) you can replace *constant* values with parameters.  You cannot replace other types of values:

- Identifiers (table names, column names, etc.)
- Operators
- Function names
- SQL key words

In other words, parameter replacement is *not* string substitution.  You can do that in the application when you are constructing the query string.  But you cannot pass the value as a parameter.  Note:  Be careful doing this in the application because the code is subject to SQL injection attacks.

Sometimes, I handle the identifier replacement by doing something like:

```
SET @SQL = 'SELECT * FROM customer where @boxContent = @text';

SET @SQL = REPLACE(@SQL, '@boxContent', @boxContent);
```

(This is T-SQL syntax.)  That is, the value is replaced before the query is executed.

This may seem like an arcane restriction.  But one of the purposes of prepared statements is to pre-compile the query -- saving on the expensive of parsing, compiling, and optimizing the query.  In an environment where you have many small queries all of the same form being processed, this can be an important performance enhancement.

Comment: Thank you for your answer i'll try later ! :D

Answer (score 1):

No, that's wrong. You can't have the column name dynamically replaced like that. Rather you can do like below and replace the value of `boxContent` variable

```
cmd.CommandText = $"SELECT * FROM client where {boxContent} = @text ";
```

If you are using C# version lower than 6 then use `string.Format()`

```
cmd.CommandText = string.Format("SELECT * FROM client where {0} = @text ", boxContent);
```

Comment: Thank you too for your answer i'll try !